# How can i make mongoose return objectID?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im  trying to get mongoose to return de objectID of this Schema. [Result in here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mHMf.png) [Schema in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHfSd.png)

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true, hide: true },
    role: { type: String, required: true }, // admin, tec, user
    requests: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Request' }]
});
```

This is my query.

```
User.find(function (err, users) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            } else {
                res.json(users);
            }
        })
```

Can i make mongoose return the objectID for every object ?

Comment: Have you tried to define the `_id` in the schema? I think it won't return anything that is not defined in the schema. So try to add `... new Schema({ _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ...`

Comment: It was the first thing i tried, it doesn't work. I dont know if has something to do with using mongo Altas. Im just probably going insane XD. https://imgur.com/GWyJRuP